# add reversed indices based on indicator

Tags: r, vector

I have a vector like this

```
v <- c(0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0)
```

I now want to generate a second vector that counts backwards until it hits a 1, then starts over.

The result here would be

```
r <- c(6,5,4,3,2,1,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,4,3,2,1,0)
```

the last zero should be kept

I tried something like this but cannot get it to work:

```
lv <- c(1, which(v == 1))

res <- c()
for(i in 1:(length(lv)-1)) {
  res <- c(res, rev(lv[i]:lv[i+1]))
}
```

Comment: @RonakShah it should stop after the last 1 it finds and keep the remaining zeros

Comment: but that would not be always 0 right? So anything after last 1 should be as it is?

Comment: @RonakShah in my case it would always be a zero, but if you have a solution that generalizes to just keep everything that would also be good

Comment: just updated the answer with the modification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `ave` creating groups with `cumsum` and count the sequence in `reverse` in each group. We then re assign 1 to their original position in `new_seq`.

```
new_seq <- ave(v, cumsum(v==1), FUN = function(x) rev(seq_along(x))) + 1
new_seq[v == 1] <- 1

new_seq
#[1] 6 5 4 3 2 1 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 4 3 2 1 2
```

---

**Update**

To keep everything after last 1 as it is we can do

```
#Make groups
indx <- cumsum(v==1)

#Create reverse sequential counting in each group
new_seq <- ave(v, indx, FUN = function(x) rev(seq_along(x))) + 1

#Keep everything after last 1 as it is
new_seq[which.max(indx) : length(v)] <- v[which.max(indx) : length(v)]

#Change 1's same as their original position
new_seq[v == 1] <- 1

new_seq
#[1] 6 5 4 3 2 1 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 4 3 2 1 0
```

Comment: A one-line variant: `ave(v, rev(cumsum(rev(v))), FUN = function(x) {if(length(x) > 1) rev(seq_along(x)) else x})`.

Comment: @mt1022 Thanks. I was going to go with something like that but it was becoming too complicated, so decided to break it down into steps. However, your solution would not work for `v <- c(0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0)` since OP wants to keep everything as it is after last 1.

Comment: I failed to anticipate that! A quick fix is to replace `if(length(x) > 1) `with `if(sum(x) > 0)`. It finally becomes: `ave(v, rev(cumsum(rev(v))), FUN = function(x) {if(sum(x) > 0) seq(length(x), 1) else x})`.

Comment: yup..that should work since OP has only 0's in the end.